Excel Cell is empty after assignment in VBA
After executing a VBA Cell Assignment, the cell is empty. In the code below, all cell assignments (such as .Cells(outRow, 10).Value = providerLast) do not update the value of the cell.
The variable values being transferred to each cell have confirmed values and are not empty. No error messages appear during the assignments.
Dim providerLast As String
Dim providerFirst As String

Dim providerEmail As String

Dim staffString As String
Dim staffList() As String
Dim staffEmail As String
        
With Workbooks("1-May-2024 MASTERS LEVEL SUPERVISOR_SUPERVISEE SPREADSHEET.xlsm").Worksheets("Current")

    outRow = 2
    currentRow = 2
    
    While Not (IsEmpty(.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value) And IsEmpty(.Cells(currentRow, 2).Value))
    
        ' Get the current provider.
   
        providerLast = .Cells(currentRow, 1).Value

   
        providerFirst = .Cells(currentRow, 2).Value  
        
        providerEmail = LookupEmail(RTrim(providerFirst) & " " & RTrim(providerLast))
        
        staffString = .Cells(currentRow, 5).Value
    
        If Len(RTrim(staffString)) > 0 Then
        
            staffList = Split(staffString, ",")
            
            For i = LBound(staffList, 1) To UBound(staffList, 1)
            
                staffEmail = LookupEmail(staffList(i))
            
                Debug.Print providerLast
                ' No assignment made below. 
                .Cells(outRow, 10).Value = providerLast 

                Debug.Print providerFirst
                ' No assignment made below.
                .Cells(outRow, 11).Value = providerFirst

                .Cells(outRow, 12).Value = staffList(i)
                .Cells(outRow, 13).Value = providerEmail
                .Cells(outRow, 14).Value = staffEmail


Maybe If Len(RTrim(staffString)) > 0 Then isn't true?

Which cell is empty?

Try using debug.print to see the values of providerLast, providerFirst, etc... just before assigning the values to the cells

Not (IsEmpty(.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value) And IsEmpty(.Cells(currentRow, 2).Value)) returns True even if one of the cell is empty and the other one not... So, the condition looks wrong and one of providerLast or providerFirst can be NullString... Try .Cells(currentRow, 1).Value <> "" And  .Cells(currentRow, 2).Value <> ""...

My apologies the .Cells(outRow, 10).Value = providerLast and    .Cells(outRow, 11).Value = providerFirst result in empty cells even when providerLast and providerFirst are not empty.

Think I will move to a C# app with EPPlus...
